# Cant login after updates to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: updates, 14.04, login

I can't log in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS after I accepted the usual Software Updater updates this morning, including codec updates and the latest Thunderbird release. Now when I enter my usual login and password, the system seems to load the desktop as usual but then gets stuck indefinitely.

Only the guest login will allow me to see a plain desktop with no privileges.

I tried to apply the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or the `XAuthority` manips found in similar threads, but here again I can't sudo anything without prior typing my admin User login & password. From there on I only get an obvious error message: invalid User/Login.

How come such a simple update suddenly change/overwrite your regular user account password, I already lost half-a-day of work because of this.

Please advise on how I can get my user account logging in normally just as this very morning before I downloaded these updates.

Thanks for your support & sound answers.

Comment: Does this fix the issue? [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) or [Ubuntu gets stuck in a Login Loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. The links above didn't help. Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I just had same, or similar problem.  I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS last week, and this morning, I accepted a bunch of updates.  It was a lot of updates, apparently, because it took quite a while.  I was instructed to restart the computer, and after I did so, I couldn't log on to the desktop.

I began searching for answers, and found this page.  After following advice above, to search for the answer at [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop).  After logging in at a prompt using Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6], I saw that my .Xauthority didn't belong to root, but belonged to my username.  However, I noticed that "." belonged to root.

I entered `chown username:username .` and my problem was solved.